# tinymce don't focus on page load

Tags: jquery, load, focus, tinymce, pageload

I'm dynamically adding a textarea onto my page as a form element and then initializing it as a [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) editor with the [jQuery Version](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_version.php). However, whenever I load the `tinymce` editor it focuses on the editor, scrolling halfway down the form. Is there any way to get `tinymce` not to focust on the editor once loaded? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this bug only occurs if there is a `#` present in the url. i.e., my url was:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/tinymce/#
```

However, if you remove the `#`, this bug does not occur. I found the solution in the tinymce forum on this [post](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=104280#p104280).

The bug is also mentioned in this [post](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=295) as well, in case anyone finds anything useful there.